# How to update nested field inside a document in Firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with Flutter and Cloud Firestore, and I'm stuck on the point where I need to update a nested field inside my collection -> document. Below is the screenshot of my firestore collection structure. I know how to do basic update method like `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection_path').doc('data').update(...)`, however, in my case, the document structure is a bit complex so I need some help in case of performing update method.

[image]

Here, I need to change (on a button press) the field `status` to `true/false` under `strategies` array.
I have the access to `strategyName` field so that I could get that item in the `strategies` array and change it...

What I tried:

```
ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          // status=true
                           final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection(widget.symbol + '_Live')
                              .doc("data")
                              .get();
                          final data = value.data();
                          final strategies =
                              data!['strategies'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
                          final strategy = strategies.firstWhere(
                              (item) => item['strategyName'] == strategyName,
                              orElse: () => Map());
                          strategy['status'] = true;
                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection(widget.symbol + '_Live')
                              .doc("data")
                              .update(data);
                        },
                        child: Text("Start"),
                      ),
```

Obviously, this won't work because here I'm just changing it locally, i.e. not using the Firestore `update` method to **actually** change the field. But I'm confused as to how to update that nested field.

Any leads/help would be really appreciated!

**EDIT**:

1. I did as you told and edited my answer, but now the error is gone but nothing seems to work, i.e. in firestore, there is no change in the data doc.
2. `ERROR`: `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update `value` map locally, then store it back:

```dart
final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(symbol + '_Live')
      .doc("data")
      .get();

  final data = value.data();

  final strategies =
      data!['strategies'].map((item) => item as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();

  final strategy = strategies.firstWhere(
      (item) => item['strategyName'] == strategyName,
      orElse: () => Map());

  strategy['status'] = toggleValue;

  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(symbol + '_Live')
      .doc("data")
      .update(data);
```

The point is to store the entire `value`.

**EDIT by Author** : Just needed to map each element to `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, it is throwing the following error when I start : `Unhandled Exception: type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Object?>' in type cast`, after I made changes to the `.update(value)` line to `.update(value as Map<String, Object?>)`.

Comment: You need to use `value.data()` instead of plain `value`. Please see the updated answer

Comment: Yes I did, please check the question again.

Comment: I guess, we are not using the `val['status']` value after setting it to `true/false`. Could that be a problem?

Comment: My answer was a bit incorrect. I've updated it, please take a look

Comment: Changed! but still, getting new error. Edited the question.

Comment: I don't have a time to write the code for you, but what you should do is to iterate over `data['strategies']` and map each element to `Map<String, dynamic>`. Then you would be able to update `status`

Comment: Thank you for your time, and I managed to make it work :D Thank you sir! Made changes to your answer.